# Calling a member function pointer on a smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, pointer-to-member

When dealing with class member function pointers, we can call a function on an object instance with the following syntax:

```
struct X {
    void foo();
};

X x;                // Instance
auto f = &X::foo;   // Member function pointer

(x.*f)();           // Call function f on x
```

When having a raw pointer of an instance, the syntax is this:

```
X *xptr = new X();

(xptr->*f)();
```

This nicely follows the analogy of a static function call:

```
x.foo();
x->foo();
```

However, when I have a **smart pointer** of the class, this doesn't work:

```
unique_ptr<X> xsptr(new X());

(xsptr->*f)();    // g++: error: no match for 'operator->*' in 'xsptr ->* f'
```

I work around this issue by first applying the dereferencing operator, then calling with the `.` syntax:

```
((*xsptr).*f)();
```

How ugly is this?

Is the compiler supposed to reject the arrow-syntax from above? Because normally (when statically calling a function), it calls `operator ->`. Shouldn't `->*` also just call `operator ->`?

The compiler error partly answers this question: The error reads as we can overload `operator ->*` to call a member function pointer on a dereferenced object, which `unique_ptr` doesn't. But this introduces more questions. Why don't smart pointers do this, if the language requires this? Is it intended *not* to do so because it introduces other issues? And why do we have to write this operator at all instead of implicitly call the member function pointer on the object returned by `->`? (As this is the behavior when writing `xsptr->foo()`)

Comment: Why should `->*` for a non-pointer value do anything? The compiler doesn't know that `unique_ptr` is trying to imitate a raw pointer. `operator->*` is overloadable, though, but it is annoying to implement it cleanly.

Comment: @Xeo I mean, the standard could well-define a default behavior for `->*`, namely "call the member pointer on the object returned by `operator->`", as something like the following: `operator ->*(memptr) { return ((*this)->).*memptr(); }`. But since it does *not* do this, why do the pointer types in C++11 not have this operator defined? Is there a reason?

Comment: Ah, and I guess this also applies for C++03.

Comment: And now tell me how you pass arguments to the called member function with your "example implementation". :) This should also tell you why in C++03 it sucks even more - no perfect forwarding.

Comment: Encapsulate it and don't think about it again: `call(xsptr, f, args);`

Comment: That was only the basic idea. I never implemented a member calling operator, so I don't know. Maybe variadic template args?

Comment: @PeterWood And what is `call`? Is there `std::call` or do you mean I could implement a generic `call` function which handles this for me?

Comment: Yes, implement `call` yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the compiler supposed to reject the arrow-syntax from above? Because normally (when statically calling a function), it calls operator ->. Shouldn't ->* also just call operator ->?

The compiler is right in rejecting the syntax. No `operator->*` should not call `operator->` (according to the standard). Note that while the syntax might look similar, `->*` is an operator on itself, not the composition of `->` with some other `*` *thing*.

Comment: Yeah so far so good. I just learned this, thanks! :) But: How to consistently solve this issue? Suppose I have a template argument `T` which can either be a raw pointer or a smart pointer, `t` being an instance of that, and `f` the pointer to call on `t`. I currently write `((*t).*f)()` which is ugly but seems to work.

Comment: @leemes: `auto& obj = *p; (obj.*f)(stuff...)`

Comment: @Xeo Which is the same, isn't it? (Let's say I need the dereferenced object only for this single expression.)

Comment: @leemes: If it's just for that single expression, what do you care? Also, `std::bind(f, p, stuff...)()`, will become `((*t).*f)(stuff...)` for this example.

Comment: @leemes: You cannot. You need to use the facilities that the language provides, there is no way of mimicking `operator->` followed by `operator.*`. While smart pointers could offer a similar functionality internally with the help of templates, it would produce code bloat (a new function for each member type in each class type for which you used this) and offer little advantages (pointers to members are not really that common in real code), and it would not be `operator->*`. The whole pointer-to-member syntax and semantics are a bit off and most don't even care :)

Comment: Thank you both for helping me understanding this. :)

Comment: @leemes: I stand corrected you can implement it as being `operator->*` for data members. I am not sure it could be done for non-data members (i.e. function members) as I cannot figure out what the type returned from the overloaded `operator->*` should be (for a pointer `U*` and a pointer to member `T U::*`, the return is defined as `T&`, but that does not quite cut it in the case of member functions).

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the `operator->*` for smart pointers. See [this](http://aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf) article by Scott Meyers. The basic idea is to return a function object which will be called after returning from operator.

The article is a bit outdated in terms that you can now use just one variadic template for variable function argument number.

Comment: Of course you can! You just have to define it outside the class. E.g., for unique_ptr the code would be something like this:
`template <typename T, typename ReturnType>
const PMFC<T, ReturnType, ReturnType (T::*)()> operator->*(const std::unique_ptr<T> &pObj, ReturnType (T::*pmf)())
{
 return std::make_pair(pObj.get(), pmf);
}`